# FFT Calculating incorrectly - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fft

I am trying to take the fast Fast Fourier Transform. I am basing my calculation off of the [Surge](https://github.com/mattt/Surge). I am having trouble getting correct results. When I take the fft of a 1000 hz sound I get something that looks like this. [image: FFT using surge]. When i take the same tone and use python I get something that looks way more correct[image: python code]. The python code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
import numpy.fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FILENAME = 'beep.wav'

fs, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(FILENAME)
data = data[:801]
spacing = 1 / float(fs)
freq = numpy.fft.rfft(data)
freq_power = np.abs(freq)
a = 1 / (2 * spacing)
b = (len(data) + 1) // 2
freq_axis = np.linspace(0, a, b)
plt.plot(freq_axis, freq_power)
plt.show()
```

The swift code looks like

```
import Accelerate
public func sqrt(x: [Float]) -> [Float] {
var results = [Float](count: x.count, repeatedValue: 0.0)
vvsqrtf(&results, x, [Int32(x.count)])

return results
}

public func fft(input: [Float]) -> [Float] {
var real = [Float](input)
var imaginary = [Float](count: input.count, repeatedValue: 0.0)
var splitComplex = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &real, imagp: &imaginary)

let length = vDSP_Length(floor(log2(Float(input.count))))
let radix = FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2)
let weights = vDSP_create_fftsetup(length, radix)
println(weights)
vDSP_fft_zip(weights, &splitComplex, 1, 8, FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))

var magnitudes = [Float](count: input.count, repeatedValue: 0.0)
vDSP_zvmags(&splitComplex, 1, &magnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(input.count))

var normalizedMagnitudes = [Float](count: input.count, repeatedValue: 0.0)
vDSP_vsmul(sqrt(magnitudes), 1, [2.0 / Float(input.count)], &normalizedMagnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(input.count))
vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(weights)

return normalizedMagnitudes
}
```

To reiterate. The swift code is the code giving unexpected results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't show the equivalent of the wave file read for Swift.  Have you verified (by printout, etc.) that the input data and length to your Swift fft is similar to what you get from your Python wave file read?

Comment: how do you resolve this?

Comment: I am also using the Swift Surge library to perform FFTs and am getting different results than I do if I just use MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Swift Float arrays with the Accelerate framework, but you might instead need to allocate your vectors using `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` types since the Accelerate framework is an Objective C framework. Here is an example how to do this.

```
public func sqrt(x: [Float]) -> [Float] {
    // convert swift array to C vector
    var temp = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.alloc(x.count)
    for (var i=0;i<x.count;i++) {
        temp[i] = x[i];
    }
    var count = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.alloc(1)
    count[0] = Int32(x.count)
    vvsqrtf(temp, temp, count)
    // convert C vector to swift array
    var results = [Float](count: x.count, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    for (var i=0;i<x.count;i++) {
        results[i] = temp[i];
    }
    // Free memory
    count.dealloc(1)
    temp.dealloc(x.count)
    return results
}
```

It will work out better for performance to use the `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` types throughout your code for your vectors of data rather than converting back and forth in function calls as I did for this example. Also you should save your FFT setup and reuse that as well for better performance.

Since you're using the vDSP FFT you might also like the `vDSP_zvabs` API which calculates magnitude in dB from the FFT results.

Finally be sure to read this link on data packing and scaling for the Accelerate framework FFT APIs.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html

To improve performance, the vDSP APIs do not output the most obvious scale values (since you will undoubtedly be scaling the data anyway somewhere else) and they pack in some extra data into a few of the FFT points.

Comment: By convention, Swift does not use parentheses after the for loop